# Openerp act_window label

Tags: python, odoo

I am newbie in Openerp. I have the next code in a xml file . I don't understand the functionality. it's calling there any Python function?

```
<act_window
        context="{'search_default_partner_id': [active_id], 'default_partner_id': active_id}"
        id="act_res_partner_2_sale_order"
        name="Quotations and Sales"
        groups="base.group_sale_salesman"
        res_model="sale.order"
        src_model="res.partner"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

all information that you need :
https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/2_7_menu_action/7_2_actions/